# How to disable the default behavior of log press cordova android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, cordova

It's `Jquery`, `html`, `css` based application using Cordova to build APK.

I have another function performing with long press on screen, it's working by clicking on the middle of two strings, to avoid default dialog. Most of the time default device long press dialog popup appears on top of the screen. How do I disable the top part showing in below screenshot? Tried some `css` and `Javascript` tricks but nothing helps.

[Check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEejs.png)

Here is the code for long press dialog

```
$(document).on("mousedown touchstart","#table_discrepancy tr", function() {

 var orderno = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
 var workorderno = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();

 var timer = setTimeout(function() {

    server('/get_customer_info/' + orderno, function(result){

     var cus_name = result.name.replace(/^[\s]+/, '');
     cus_name = cus_name.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
     var phone_no = result.phoneno.replace(/^[\s]+/, '');
     var email = result.email.replace(/^[\s]+/, '');

          $('#customer_info_modal').modal('show');

          $('#orderno_modal').html('Order# : ' + orderno);
          $('#workorderno_modal').html('Work Order# : ' + workorderno);
          $('#customer_name_modal').html('Name : ' + cus_name);
          $('#customer_phoneno_modal').html('Phone#: ' + phone_no);
          $('#customer_email_modal').html('Email: ' + email);
    });

    }, 1000);

$(this).on("mouseup touchstart", function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
})
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: did you tried mouseup , mousedown ?

Comment: Yes @AghoriTantrik

Comment: Code added @Observer

Comment: Try to do "mousedown touchstart" and "mouseup touchstart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocked by adding `CSS` with class define in body, it doesn't allow to select anything from the screen

```
.noselect {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
   -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
   -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
   -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome and Opera *
     }
```